# Find upper limit for this probability using Chebychev's inequality.

Tags: probability

If $X$ is a continuous random variable which is distributed evenly in (0,10):

a)How do we compute **exactly** $P\{|X-5| \gt 4\}$?

b)Can we give an upper limit using Chebyshev's inequality and how?

*Can someone get to the final solution of b (Abishanka Saha made a good start)? It would help **very much**.

Comment: Given distribution is uniform on (0,10), find the p.d.f of uniform distribution.

Comment: The Chebyshev Inequality will give a **lower** bound for the probability in (a). It will give an upper bound for the probability that $|X-\mu| \ge 4$. Do check the wording of the question.

Comment: Sir André you are right. Please if you can answer with some theory between the steps I would be thankful....

Answer (score 1):

$$P(|X-5|<4)=P(1<X<9)=\frac{8}{10}$$
Chevychev's Inequality says that
$$P(|X-\mu|<\epsilon)\leq\frac{E(X^2)}{\epsilon^2}$$
Here $\mu=5$, $\epsilon=4$, Find $EX^2$ for the given distribution.
See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality)

Comment: First question: How did we get ${8 \over 10}$?

Comment: Andre was right... there was an error in the wording of the question. Editing it right now

Comment: The distribution is uniform over the interval $(0,10)$, so the probability of choosing a point from the interval $(1,9)$ is the length of the interval $(1,9)$ divided by the length of the interval $(0,10)=\frac{9-1}{10-0}=\frac{8}{10}$

Comment: For a again: What if we had (0,1)?*

Comment: *It's for $P\{|X-{1 \over 2}| \ge {1 \over 3}\}$ (so different approach I guess?)

Comment: We have $ {1 \over 6} \le X \le {5 \over 6}$ then it would be ${ {{5 \over 6} - {1 \over 6}} \over {1 - 0} }$ right?

Comment: Nopes, exactly the same approach...because $P(|X-\frac{1}{2}|\geq\frac{1}{3})=P(\{X\leq\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}\}\cup\{X\geq\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{2}\})=$length of $(0,1/6)\cup(5/6,10)$ divided by the length of $(0,10)$. So it will be $\frac{1/6+(10-5/6)}{10}.$

Comment: If it was (0,1) then we whould have $\frac{1/6+(10-5/6)}{1-0}$ right?

Comment: Sorry we are getting out of topic.... Can you edit the answer for the topics question with some more details about Chevychev? (How to apply the values/formula etc)